# Get site name in config file

Tags: sxa

Is it possible to get current running site name in .config or patch file in multiple site in Sitecore SXA ?

I did not find anything related to it.

Comment: Not exactly getting that you want to find out in your C# code or in Powershell?

Comment: As Michael mentioned SXA does not store site names in config files. What is your actual problem?

Comment: I am trying to override .config file in muliple site environment and each site has unique page to show through patch file. If I will get Sitename in patch file then it will resolve my issue.

Comment: When working with SXA you shouldn't put site names in (patch) config files. Use the properties of the site instead as those can be set on the site item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Site names in SXA are not stored in configuration files. You can check out the SXA Site Manager found under the Toolbox to see what is available. You can use the Sitecore API to query for the sites.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. Only one concern , can we use Sitecore API in .config file?

Comment: The Sitecore API will combine results from the files and item provides.